# Yii2: Using TinyMCE into Kartik's DetailView with custom settings

Tags: yii2, tinymce, detailview

I'd like to insert 2amigos' TinyMCE widget in Kartik's DetailView edit mode. This is what I got by now:

```
       [
           'attribute' => 'myAttribute',
           'format' => 'raw',
           'type' => 'widget',
           'widgetOptions' => ['class' => TinyMce::classname()],
           'value' => $model->myAttribute,
        ],
```

With this chunk I managed to show TinyMCE editor with default settings. What I'm trying to do now is to show it with custom settings defined by:

`Yii::$app->params['myTinyMceParams']`

In form I'm doing this:

`<?= $form->field($model, 'myAttribute')->widget(TinyMce::className(), Yii::$app->params['myTinyMceParams']) ?>`

Any ideas?

Comment: What are those params? They are not working or what? :)

Comment: Those are TinyMCE config params. They work if I fed them straight into ActiveForm as in the last snippet, but now I'm trying to find out a way of doing the same thing in Kartik's DetailView.

Comment: For instance, doing something like `'widgetOptions' => ['class' => TinyMce::classname(), Yii::$app->params['myTinyMceParams']]` won't work. However if I do `'widgetOptions' => ['class' => TinyMce::classname(), <array_of_params>]`it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution, maybe not ideal but fully operative: to merge both 'class' array and rest-of-options array into 'widgetOptions':

```
'widgetOptions' => ArrayHelper::merge(['class' => TinyMce::classname()], Yii::$app->params['tinyMceParams']),
```